# Disable react-native-modalize scrolling

Tags: react-native

I am using react-native-modalize package for modal in react-native and I want to disable the scrolling feature to close the modal.

I have tried

```
tapGestureEnabled={false}
```

But it's not working, and I searched the docs for prop for this scenrio, but I couldn't find any. Is there a way to disable the scroll and prevent the modal from closing ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you wanted to do the following:

```
<Modalize
  panGestureEnabled={false}
```